# How to update a Model after Reading Data from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to write an App in AngularJS and at some point I update my Data via a Form:

```
<h3> Anzeige </h3>

<form name="anzeige-form" ng-controller="AnzeigeController as anzCtrl" ng-submit="anzCtrl.getMyOrder()">
    <label for="id">Meine Bestellnummer</label><input type="text" required class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="anzCtrl.id" placeholder="0..X" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Laden / Aktualisieren</button>


<div class="ausgabe">
Ihre Adresse : {{anzCtrl.myorder.order.address}}
<ul class="list-unstyled anzeige">
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="pizza in anzCtrl.myorder.order.cart">
        <h3>{{pizza.name}}</h3><br/>
        <span class="status" ng-if="pizza.status=0">Bestellt</span>
        <span class="status" ng-if="pizza.status=1">Im Ofen</span>
        <span class="status" ng-if="pizza.status=2">Lieferbereit</span>
        <span class="status" ng-if="pizza.status=3">Unterwegs</span>
        <span class="status" ng-if="pizza.status=4">Lieferbereit</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{pizza.status}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="4" style="width: {{pizza.status * 25}}%">
                <span class="sr-only">{{pizza.status * 25}}% Abgeschlossen</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

The Angular Code looks like this:

```
.controller('AnzeigeController',function($http){

    //$scope.adress = '';
    this.id = 21;
    //this.myorder = order2;
    this.myorder = {};
    //$scope.myarray = {};

    this.getMyOrder = function(){

        $http.get('get_by_id.php',{params:{"id": this.id}}).success(function(datar){

            this.myorder = angular.fromJson(datar);
            console.log(this.myorder);
        })
    }
})
```

My Problem is now, I don't know how to tell Angular that an asynchronous update has occured and my List will Update with the right values. Logging the myorder variable gives me a correct Object in the debugger / console.

I mostly don't understand how to access the data, because the Line {{anzCtrl.myorder.order.address}} doesn't show anything.

I have a major thinking error is my guess.
Pls clarify how to do it correctly.

Best Regards, Marc

Comment: there is no need to tell angular that an asynchronous update has occurred. angular updates this automatically when using  $http.get. the error must be somewhere else.  try debugging the scope on the DOM using jquery and $(selector).scope()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` no longer refers to the controller model when your promise resolves. You need to create another variable to hold `this` and then use this other variable when your promise resolves.

```
.controller('AnzeigeController', function($http) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.id = 21;
    _this.myorder = {};

    _this.getMyOrder = function() {
        $http.get('get_by_id.php',{params:{"id": _this.id}}).success(function(datar){
            _this.myorder = angular.fromJson(datar);
            console.log(_this.myorder);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: very nice, now it works! Have to get working on the rest of my code. :)

Comment: Glad it works. Please consider marking this as the answer to your question so it won't continue to show up on the list of questions with no answers.